# Events stopped coming from Flurry after Gradle update

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have a problem with getting data from flurry analytics... At the moment I am working on an Android project that has existed for more than a year and therefore I will say right away that everything is in order with the integration and use in the flurry project.

The problem is that after updating the "com.android.tools.build:gradle" library from 7.0.4 to 7.1.0 and newer, the events stop coming and no errors occur, when I return version 7.0.4 everything works Great.

In the release build we use:

```
shrinkResources true
minifyEnabled true
```

There is an assumption that R8 cuts some vital files ... But also, but the official site says that: "As of Flurry SDK 12.0.0, the Flurry SDK is provided in the AAR format, we no longer provide .jar files. Since you are adding the AAR format of the Flurry dependencies, you do not need to modify your AndroidManifest files or ProGuard configuration."

My flurry implementation: `implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:13.1.0'`

In this regard, I have a question, Can someone come across this problem and have a ready solution? Or does anyone have an idea what should be written in ProGuard?

Answer (score 0):

Try newer gradle like 7.2.1 and above instead of 7.1.0.

When using the older Android Studio 2020.3.1:

1. Create a new Android Studio projecct, the default gradle is 7.0.4.
2. **Flurry logs correctly**.
3. Change it to 7.1.0, Android Studio shows "A newer version of com.android.tools.build:gradle than 7.1.0 is available: 7.1.3".
4. Build with 7.1.0, Android Studio failed with "Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.2. Current version is 7.0.2.",  Therefore change it to 7.2.0.
5. Android Studio build failed with "This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 2021.1.1 or newer."

Upgrade to the latest Android Studio 2021.3.1:

1. Build succeed, and **Flurry logs correctly**.
2. Create a new Android Studio projecct, the default gradle is 7.2.1.
3. **Flurry logs correctly**.

If it does not resolve your issue, then try to check whether the Flurry calls been really called.
E.g., add some console logs (`System.out.println("...")`) before and after you call `Flurry.Builder.build(...)` and `FlurryAgent.logEvent(...)`. And see how they show in your Android console.